# How to find out the index creation date in elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

How to find out the index created date in elastic search?

Answer (score 16):

Elasticsearch now automatically includes the creation date for an index, for
example:

If I create a new index (with no settings)

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/aoeu'
{"acknowledged":true}
```

I can now 'get' the index to retrieve its metadata:

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/aoeu'
{
  "aoeu": {
    "aliases": {},
    "mappings": {},
    "settings": {
      "index": {
        "creation_date": "1429308615170",
        "number_of_replicas": "1",
        "number_of_shards": "5",
        "uuid": "C5sqwXClSFyd5uF3MSrVgg",
        "version": {
          "created": "1050199"
        }
      }
    },
    "warmers": {}
  }
}
```

You can see the `creation_date` field above.

Comment: You can paste this number in https://www.epochconverter.com/ to get a date quickly.

Answer (score 6):

> `curl -XGET localhost:9200/_cat/indices?h=i,creation.date.string`

Above command will output **index name (i)** and **creation date**.
For more options you can try help as-

> `curl -XGET localhost:9200/_cat/indices?help`

Answer (score 1):

From the 1.4.0 version, documentation explains the following:
[Index creation date](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-create-index.html)

> When an index is created, a timestamp is stored in the index metadata for the creation date. By default this it is automatically generated but it can also be specified using the creation_date parameter on the create index API

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/test -d '{
    "creation_date" : 1407751337000 
}'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your mapping and add a [timestamp](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-timestamp-field.html)

Comment: AFAIU It is not about document creation time, it is about index creation time.